# Expected number of wins in a higher/lower number guessing game

Tags: probability

Rules of the game:

1. Before each turn, the player guesses either "higher" or "lower".
2. On each turn, an integer $0 <= n_t <= 100$ is selected randomly and uniformly.
3. - If $n_t$ is greater than the $n$ from the previous turn (i.e. $n_t > n_{t-1}$), and the player guessed "higher", then the player wins.
   - If $n_t < n_{t-1}$, and the player guessed "lower", then the player wins.
   - Otherwise, the player loses.

For the very first turn ($t = 1$), $n_0 = 0$ (arbitrarily chosen).

The player uses this strategy to play the game:

- If $n_{t-1} < 50$, guess "higher".
- If $n_{t-1} > 50$, guess "lower".
- If $n_{t-1} = 50$, toss a fair coin, guess "higher" if heads, and guess "lower" if tails.

My questions are:

1. Suppose the player uses the strategy above to play the game for 100 turns. What is the expected number of wins?
2. Would the expected number of wins be different if $n_0$ was some other number (e.g. $n_0 = 50$)?
3. Would the expected proportion of wins be different if there were more turns (e.g. 100,000 turns instead of 100 turns)?

I used the Python script below to get an approximate answer to question 1. It simulates 100,000 games of 100 turns each, with $n_0 = 0$. The average number of wins seems to be around $74.7$. I get a similar answer when I use NumPy's random number generator (`n = np.random.randint(0, 101)`) instead of the one in Python's standard library. How should I approach the problem if I want an analytical solution instead?

```
import random
import statistics

game_results = []

# 100,000 games.
for _ in range(100_000):
    num_wins = 0

    previous_n = 0
    guess_higher = True

    # 100 turns per game.
    for _ in range(100):
        # Player's strategy.
        if previous_n < 50:
            guess_higher = True
        elif previous_n > 50:
            guess_higher = False
        elif previous_n == 50:
            guess_higher = random.choice([True, False])

        n = random.randint(0, 100)  # Inclusive of 0 and 100.

        if ((n > previous_n and guess_higher) or
            (n < previous_n and not guess_higher)):
            num_wins += 1

        previous_n = n

    game_results.append(num_wins)

print('Average number of wins:', statistics.mean(game_results))
print('Sample variance:', statistics.variance(game_results))
```

Comment: Interesting homework. You could add computation of the variance to evaluate the accuracy of your empirical value.

Comment: @IAmAGuest Okay, thank you for the advice about the variance. By the way, this is not homework.

Comment: As the drawings are independent, you are rating the probability of drawing larger than a uniform number in $[0,50]$ or smaller than a uniform number in $[50,100]$. Both probabilities are $3/4$. [This is simplified, I didn't care about the ties.]

Comment: The initial value slightly influences the result. For instance, with $n_0=0$, you win with probability $100/101$ (but only at the first drawing). In terms of probabilities, this is neglectable after $100$ drawings.

Comment: @IAmAGuest Which should I calculate, the sample variance or the population variance?

Comment: You don't know the mean, so sample. But that's unimportant.

Comment: [0,49] and [51,100] are the same by symmetry, and have an average probability of 75.5/101 of winning. Weigh in the 50 case to get p = (100* 75.5/101 + 1*1/2)/101 = 0.745074

Answer (score 1):

Let $\ W_t=1\ $ if the player wins the $\ t^\text{th}\ $ round and $\ W_t=0\ $ otherwise. Then the total number of wins in $\ 100\ $ rounds is $\ \sum_\limits{t=1}^{100}W_t\ $ and the expected number of wins is $\ \sum_\limits{t=1}^{100}\mathbb{E}\big(W_t\big)\ $. Now
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\big(W_t\big)&=\mathbb{E}\big(\mathbb{E}\big(W_t\,\big|\,n_{t-1}\big)\big)\\
&=\mathbb{E}\big(P\big(W_t=1\,\big|\,n_{t-1}\big)\big)\\
\end{align}
for $\ t\ge2\ $,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\big(W_1=1\big)&=P\big(W_1=1\big)\\
&=\cases{
\frac{100-n_0}{101}&if $\ n_0\le50$\\
\frac{n_0-1}{101}&if $\ n_0>50$}\ ,
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
P\big(W_t=1\,|n\,_{t-1}\big)&=\cases{\frac{100-n_{t-1}}{101}&if $\ n_{t-1}\le50$\\
\frac{n_{t-1}-1}{101}&if $\ n_{t-1}>50$}
\end{align}
for $\ t\ge2\ $. Therefore
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\big(W_t\big)&=\mathbb{E}\big(\mathbb{E}\big(W_t\,|\,n_{t-1}\big)\big)\\
&=
\frac{1}{101^2}\Bigg(\sum_{n=0}^{50}(100-n)+\sum_{n=51}^{101}(n-1)\Big)\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle2\sum_{n=50}^{100}n}{101^2}\\
&=\frac{51\cdot150}{101^2}
\end{align}
for $\ t\ge2\ $, and so
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\Big(\sum_{t=1}^{100}W_t\Big)&=\mathbb{E}\big(W_1\big)+\frac{99\cdot51\cdot150}{101^2}\\
&=\cases{\frac{100-n_0}{101}+\frac{99\cdot51\cdot150}{101^2}&if $\ n_0\le50$\\
\frac{n_0-1}{101}+\frac{99\cdot51\cdot150}{101^2}&if $\ n_0>50$}\ .
\end{align}
For $\ n_0=0\ $, this gives the expected number of wins to be
$$
\frac{100}{101}+\frac{99\cdot51\cdot150}{101^2}\approx75.2\ .
$$